# how to give job attributes from java.awt.JobAttributes to java.awt.print.Printable

Tags: java, graphics, printing, awt

I want to print. I am creating instance of graphics and printing. I am using the method
`java.awt.print.Printable.print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)`
.
I don't want to show the print dialog, i have achieved this by not calling the method
`PrinterJob.printDialog()` but I have multiple printer connected to my computer, my program will automatically print to the printer I want and will not ask the user. This can be achieved by the
`JobAttributes.setPrinter("printer to be used")`.
But i can't find any way to give this JobAttributes to the pint(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) method. Please help me.

Comment: I hope you're not calling the print method directly. It should only be called by PrintJob

Comment: You might want to read through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/JPSTOC.fm.html